# Can't find parent Url in zend-framework

Tags: url, zend-framework, url-helper

i have two Zend Framework site in one folder.one is in folder name "short/" other in "short/mobile/".I want the mobile Zend Frameworkversion can access the short folder,
like if i use

```
<?php echo baseurl()?>/images
```

Its go to "short/mobile/images",
but i want to go to "short/images"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This came to me for review as it's your first post.  You'll get the best help on here if you specify what research you've done to resolve your problem and why it didn't work.  In particular, for instance, you need to explain what documentation [you've looked at](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html) and why it's not applicable / didn't work for you.

Comment: `$request->setBaseUrl('')` for your mobile version. BTW usually is better to have both versions in one Zend instance.